# Can I cast object to An Interface or a new class

Tags: c#, object, casting, dependency-properties

I have a silverlight app
In the app there are a number of user controls with data grids in them that relate to things such as Purchase Orders, sale orders, transfers etc.

What these have in common is a "document Type", "Document No." type structure.

I am trying to implement a generic priting function whereby i get the Order and then send this back to a HOST erp system to create a PDF for viewing.

I was trying to avoid having to add the same functioanlity to all the screens, so I created a Print Report user control with a print button on it. the user control has a View model behind it and some dependcy properties on it.

The idea is that when the user selects an Order from one of the grids the we set the dependcy prop as the selected item from the grid. To accomodate this the dependency property is of type object.

as the dependcy property is set i can pcik up the obejct in the callback method defined in the regstration of the DP. Iso e.value is either sales Order, Transfer Order, Purchase order.

```
private static void UpdatedTheValues(DependencyObject d, 
                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

    var sender = d as NavReportPicker;
    if (sender != null)
    {
        PrintObjModel bbb = (PrintObjModel) e.NewValue;

    }
}
```

I can push this property around, in that i can pass it to a method on the view model but at no point can i do anythhing else with it.

A colleague suggested that to make things cleaner perhaps adding an interface the to Sale Order, transfer ORder, Purcashe ORder classes would enable me to cast the object to either an Interface or some other "shared class" by calling a method on the interface e..g

```
public NewPrintObj GetNewObject()
{
    PrintObj p = new PrintObj;
    p.No=1;
    p,type=2;
}
```

This all seems a fairly good idea, but i am unable to convert/cast  the dependcy Property object to anything else.

If i cast i get invalid cast exception, If i safely cast then I get a null.

Comment: Please post code that _can_ compile. Your second code block can't compile.

Comment: @Oded why does it matter if the second example doesn't compile? Do you want him to write a static void Main() too?

Comment: @MattDavey - Examples of code should be at least compilable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand how the objects are all related (do all of the orders derive from `PrintObjModel`?)

My answer would be to place a breakpoint in the dependency property change event and look at the content of `e.NewValue`. This will then allow you to see what you do have and whether it should be possible to cast to a `PrintObjModel`.

Either the value in `e.NewValue` isn't what you're expecting, or the thing which you are expecting doesn't derive from what you think it does.